# Kivy usando raspberry pi 3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-kivy

Estou usando a saída HDMI do *Raspberry Pi 3*. Utilizando um código *Python* que abre uma janela *Kivy*, está janela preenche toda a tela e sobrepõem todo o resto(janelas abertas, ponteiro do *mouse*...). Aparentemente ele(*rasp*) responde os comandos, pois é possível desligar, mas na janela não é possível fazer nada. Como posso corrigir possibilitando usa-lá normalmente?

```
import kivy 
kivy.require('1.0.6') 
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
class MyApp(App): 
   def build(self):
      return Label(text='Hello world') 
if name == 'main':
   MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Aparentemente tem algumas pessoas com a [mesma *issue*](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/_CKVtjSHC3w), mas até agora não apareceu solução :/